# Upload multiple files yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

Tell me where I was wrong, everything is tried

my view file:

```
echo FileInput::widget([
 'model' => $model,
 'attribute' => 'files[]',
 'options' => ['multiple' => true]
]);
```

Also i added

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```

enctype option to form element

Model:
i add two variables as property:

```
public $files; // files instance
public $serialize; // set string which store the files
```

in rules 
serialize as string, and files:

```
[['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'gif, jpg, png, pdf, doc, docx', 'maxFiles' => 10],
```

and controller action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $oldFiles = $model->serialize;
            $files = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'files');

            if($files === false){
              $model->serialize = $oldFiles;
            } else {
              $serialize = [];

              if($model->validate()){
                foreach($files as $file){
                  $ext = end((explode(".", $file)));
                  $filename = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
                  $serialize[] = $filename;
                  $file->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/image/' . $filename);
                }
              } else {

              }
              //print_r($model->getErrors()); die();
              $model->serialize = serialize($serialize);
            }
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->news_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

So, `$files` is empty, why?
also i get a "4" code error in `$_FILES` array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32219846/2559712

Comment: what errors you get?

Comment: BTW, documentation isn't helpful? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 1):

It should be getInstances for multiple files.

```
$files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'files');
```