# Uploading multiple image in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Uploading multiple image in yii2 doesn't work!
view:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($uploadModel, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => 'multiple', 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
   $uploadModel = new \app\models\UploadForm();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $uploadModel->imageFiles = \yii\web \UploadedFile::getInstance($uploadModel, 'imageFiles');
    if ($uploadModel->upload()) {
        echo 'successfully';
        return true;
            }else{
                 echo 'failed';
              }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
                    'uploadModel' => $uploadModel,
        ]);
    }
```

uploadModel:

```
 public $imageFiles;

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'maxFiles' => 10, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
    ];
}

public function upload() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the same problem with kartik file input widget!

Comment: Can you clarify pls. what "does not work" means? Are you getting error-msgs (which?) or is it all working nicely, but you just do get the file?

Comment: `echo failed` i dont know why? else of upload()

Comment: U must call UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles'); instaed of UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFiles');

Comment: that was the problem ! thanks

Comment: now i will post to answer for all

Comment: you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32219846/2559712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For returning  all uploaded files for the given model attribute you must call

```
UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
```

instaed of

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFiles');
```

Refer this:
[Yii::UploadFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstances()-detail)